# I need help to modify .htaccess to rewrite 2 different changes

Tags: .htaccess

I already direct people from my www.example.com website to example.com.
Now I am looking to direct them from example.com to https://example.com
Would this take 2 different rewrites?
I apologize that I can not find this answered anywhere I have looked.
Thank you and Bess You,
Pete

Comment: I use in my htaccess file now: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add these two lines to your `/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

[[source](https://github.com/phanan/htaccess#force-https)]

You can also use a better approach to trim the "www.":

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

So your file should now look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Trim www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike,Should it be written as such:?   RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\example\.com [NC] RewriteRule (.*) example.com/$1 [R=301,L]  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ?

Comment: Updated answer. Please also see [this document](https://github.com/phanan/htaccess) as a reference - it is very helpful.

Comment: Also, when asking questions on StackOverflow, be sure to put your existing code in your question (indented by four spaces). If you forget to, you can edit your question.

Comment: Thank you Mike for taking the time to help me. Your answer worked out perfect. Have a blessed day and thank you again. Pete